# For $x \in \Bbb R$, for all $y (|y|<x \implies y<5)$

Tags: propositional-calculus, quantifiers

Given that $x$ is a free variable beloging to the set of real numbers, find the set of values for $x$ for which the following statement is true:

$\forall y (|y|<x \implies y<5)$

My attempt:

- If $x < 0$ then the hypothesis $|y|<x$ is False, so the statement is True.
- If $x \geq 5$ then if $|y|$ is between $5$ and $x$, the hypothesis is True but the conclusion is False, so the statement is False.
- If $0 \leq x < 5$ then the hypothesis is True for all $|y| < x$ and the conclusion $y < 5$ is also True.

So my answer would be the set $x < 5$. However the answer in the back of the book says the set $(-\infty,0] \cup [5,\infty)$. Where am I wrong?

Comment: +1: In my opinion, your analysis is dead on accurate, **except** for your mishandling of the specific case of $x = +5$.

Comment: If $x\le 0$ then $A=\{y: |y|< x\}=\emptyset.$ So $y\in A\implies y<5.$

Comment: You're right, the answer in the back of the book is wrong ($x = 6$ does not satisfy the statement). It should be $(-\infty, 5)$.

Comment: @BrianO I fixed my answer, but I still don't understand why $x=5$ doesn't work after taking the contrapositive. I can see why in the above example, but I don't know what changes..

Comment: @DerekLuna Well darn, I missed $x = 5$: that works too. So the answer is $(-\infty, 5]$.

Comment: Thank you for your answers!  The contrapositive eases the interpretation.

Comment: @limah, you're welcome! Upvote my answer if you'd like!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the contrapositive which is logically equivalent and easier to work with:

If $\forall y( y \geq 5 \implies (|y| \geq x))\Longleftrightarrow \forall y $$( y \geq 5,\implies  (y \geq x))$ since $y \geq 0$.

If $x > 5$, then choose $y = 5$ which contradicts the statement.

Hence we must have all $x \leq 5$, specifically $(-\infty,5]$ as BrianO commented.

You missed $x = 5$, here is why it works for your original statement:

Note that $y \leq |y|$.  If $x = 5$, then the statement becomes $\forall y (y\leq|y|<5 \implies y < 5)$, which is seen to be true immediately.

Comment: Time to revise again ;) Yes, $x \le 5$.

Comment: @BrianO Hehe :).